# Differentiation with respect to a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Suppose **u** is a smooth vector valued function say **u** : $ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ and $ W $ is a smooth scalar valued function, $W$ : $ \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.  What would $ W_u(u) $ be? I think that it could look like this $$ W_u(u) = [ \dfrac{\partial W\left( u\right) }{\partial u_{1}},\ldots , \dfrac{\partial W\left( u\right) }{\partial u_{m}} ] $$ but I feel that I'm missing something that has to do maybe with the coordinates $ (x_1, \ldots , x_n) $, I'm not sure. Sadly, I do not have a solid differential geometry background.

Comment: If $W : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ as you say then I think the only reasonable interpretation is that this is the usual gradient of $W$ composed with $u$, which is what you've written. If instead you meant that $W$ takes in a *function* and outputs a scalar, then you need e.g. a norm on the space of functions $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$.

Comment: We already know that $W$ is a function for which $ W : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R $ and given some vector valued function $\textbf{u} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ we define $ W( \textbf{u} ) $ and then differentiate with respect to $\textbf{u}$. $W$ is not something general like a functional which would then require some norm to define differentiation. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I said. So "derivative of $W(u)$ with respect to $u$" is no different than saying "the derivative of $W$". But then we're abusing notation and saying also that $u$ is a function of some variable, so we plug in the function $u$ after we take the derivative of $W$. This is just like in single variable calculus where if we write $f(g(x))$ then what we mean by $df/dg$ is the function $x \mapsto f'(g(x))$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much!